# Листинг файлов подпапки

Tags: php

```
 $dir = "C:\\mess";   //задаём имя директории
    if(is_dir($dir)) {   //проверяем наличие директории
         //echo $dir.' - директория существует;<br>';
         $files = scandir($dir);    //сканируем (получаем массив файлов)
         array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '.'
         array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '..'
         for($i=0; $i<sizeof($files); $i++) {

         if(preg_match("~mess-.*\.txt~", $files[$i])) {
         echo '-файл: <a href="'.$dir."/".$files[$i].'" title="открыть/скачать файл или страницу">'.$files[$i].'</a>;<br>';  //выводим все файлы
```

проблема в том что он исчет только в папке mess, а подпапки как сканировать?

Answer (score 2):

Таким же способом, что вы и сканируете папку. Проверьте внутри цикла, является ли это каталогом, если да, тогда с помощью функции scandir, повторите такие же действие. Для простоты и удобство рекомендую создать функцию, которая будет выполнять эти действия ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function dir_files($dir) {
   if(is_dir($dir)) {
     $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
     foreach($iterator as $file) {
         echo $file->getName();   
     }
   }
}
```

Как-то так